# Python Logger not respecting log level

Tags: python, logging

Setup: Python 3.3

I have a unit test program that I want to print out log messages. Python is not printing anything but WARNING or higher messages through this logger I made, even though I set the log severity to INFO.

Here is the code I use:

```
test_logger = logging.getLogger('DesktopprTester')
print(test_logger.getEffectiveLevel())
test_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
print(test_logger.getEffectiveLevel())
test_logger.warning('WARN')
test_logger.info('INFO')
```

And here is the output:

```
30 <-30 is WARN
20 <-20 is INFO
WARN
```

It does not print INFO. So I am missing all my info statements in this file... and I am not sure why. The docs seem to agree with me. When I used to use the root logger, and set the level to info, it would print it (And all the other stuff it was doing). Now that I made my own logger, it doesn't seem to work. Note that WARNING level messages still come up, but they aren't what I want to see.

Is there something I am missing here? I feel like there's some obvious answer I'm not seeing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While running your code in python 2, you get a clear warning:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "DesktopprTester"
```

So you simply need to add a handler to your logger:

```
test_logger = logging.getLogger('DesktopprTester')
hdlr = logging.StreamHandler()
test_logger.addHandler(hdlr)
```

The warning doesn't appear on python 3 - I'm not sure why

Comment: That fixed it. The docs didn't really make that too obvious. I understood they had handlers but it makes it seem like its for redirecting to files or network streams. Thanks.

Comment: @Mgamerz that's, indeed, their purpose (on unix, at least, `stdin` and `stdout` can be considered "files"). The [example in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging) does use a handler, but it's unfortunate that `logging` doesn't provide a `StreamHandler` on loggers by default (as it does on the module)